# Wix Custom action while Preparing Setup dialog is shown

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

how can I run a custom-action while the "Preparing to install..." dialog is shown?

[Example Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2dOk.gif)

Comment: Side question: if it is _**preparing** to install_ why do you have to perform any action? The one during MSI loading won't trigger anything you can do. The second one when searching for app (and its cost) can trigger custom actions tied to `AppSearch` in `InstallExecuteSequence`.

Comment: I have a custom dialog with a drop down list and this list will be filled in a custom action. This needs some time and at the moment, the user sees nothing

Comment: I assume what you mean is that you want to run an asynchronous custom action before that dialog is shown. Or if there are other dialogs before the one you're referring to, then again just start an asynchronous CA. Just start an async CA as soons you can in the UI sequence! You'll need to invent some mechanism in the dialog so that it knows the data has been collected.